# Как создать функцию ,которая будет работать как npm модуль ,который поможет быстрее изучить зависимости проекта?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

У нас  много разных проектов, и часто трудно и долго анализировать зависимости каждого проекта.
Поэтому когда разработчики, или команда получает новый для них проект - они долго изучают, и исследуют что там в зависимостях и тд и тп
решение:
использовать чтото наподобие npm ls команду?
в общем, она строит дерево зависимостей проекта
наша цель - напедалить решение типо npm ls, но оно должно быть:
 - работать как npm модуль(т.е. в будущем его можно было использовать как отдельный пакет)
 - уметь фильтровать зависимости с помощью введеного пользователем  регулярного выражения.
 - пробовали много разных модулей , но все отражает некоректные пути?
[image: чтото вроде этого должно получиться]

Comment: Какой именно модуль из npmls читает зависимости?https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/npm/lib/ls.js

Comment: Начал реализацию модуля. С начала думаю сделать функцию поиска зависимостей .